# TypeError Passport JS username property undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am a beginner in Reactjs and nodejs trying to make my first full stack app. In my postjob schema I want the username of the current logged in user in the publisher field. Passport has a `req.user` command to get details of the current user but whenever I try to use this it gives the type error.If you guys need any other file let me know

postjob schema

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const postjobtemplate= new mongoose.Schema({

    jobtitle:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    company:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    officelocation:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    jobtype:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    publisher:{           ///<=HERE
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})

module.exports=mongoose.model("postjobtable",postjobtemplate)
```

routes js

```
router.post('/postjob',async(request,response,next)=>{
    const postjob=new postjobtemplatecopy({
        jobtitle:request.body.jobtitle,
        company:request.body.company,
        officelocation:request.body.officelocation,
        jobtype:request.body.jobtype,
        publisher:request.user.username, //////<=HERE

    })
    postjob.save()
    .then(data=>{
        response.json(data)

    })
    .catch(error=>{
        response.json(error)
    })
});

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) res.send("No User Exists");
      else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status(200).send("Successfully Authenticated");
    
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

server js

```
const express =require('express')
const app=express()
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const dotenv=require('dotenv')
const routes=require('./routes/routes')
const cors=require('cors')
const passport=require("passport")
const passportlocal = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bodyParser=require("body-parser")
const session=require("express-session") 
const cookieparser=require('cookie-parser')

dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT,{useNewUrlParser:true},()=>
console.log("database connected")
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors({
    origin:'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials:true
}))

app.use(session({
    secret:'secret',
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true
}))

app.use(cookieparser("secret"))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./passport-config')(passport);
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api',routes)

app.listen(4002,()=>console.log("server running on port 4002"))

module.exports = app;
```

passport config

```
const User = require("./models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (result === true) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
      const userInformation = {
        username: user.username,
      };
      cb(err, userInformation);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: can you show passport file? add to your question

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi added the passport config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting typeError because username is not being sent/received properly. Change this line in your post route: `publisher: request.user.username,` for this: `publisher: request.body.username,`(I assume you are sending it from the front-end as username, if not, it would be useful to include your request from React in your code) that way you are actually receiving the data you're sending from the front end. Also, if you are using a different field other than username, you need to specify it in your passport strategy like this:

```
passport.use(
    "yourStrategyName", //here you are naming the strategy to be used in your route
    new localStrategy( {
    usernameField: "publisher", //here you are telling passport to use "publisher" as a username
  },(publisher, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ publisher }, (err, user) => { //changed to the field name in database
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (result === true) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );
```

And in your route.js:

```
  router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("yourStrategyName", (err, user, info) => { //include the strategy name as the first parameter
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) res.send("No User Exists");
      else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status(200).send("Successfully Authenticated");
    
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Comment: I am not getting the username from axios the passportjs authentication is in the backend folder so is the routes.js

Comment: You are wrong. You are sending your request from the front-end (React in your case), then, you receive it  as `request.body.username` (assuming that's how you sent it as you did not provide that code) in your back-end. I edited my answer so you can also check for other errors you have in your code

Comment: my apologies still new to this